# File deleted in which process was writing

Tags: process, io, output

I had redirected all the output of a process to a file using the ">" operator from the terminal. However I accidentally deleted the file in which the write was going on. 
When I checked the process is still running. The process is a bit long and cant be stop midway. 
Is there any way in which the output being generated from the process can still be seen?
Edit: I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the PID of the process, you should be able to access the output in `/proc/[PID]/fd/1`, where you replace `[PID]` with the actual process id, such as `14512`.

Comment: Can I somehow redirect it to the correct filename so that if some other person wants to check he can directly open the file? Thanks by the way.

Comment: You can try `tail -f /proc/[PID]/fd/1 > /some/new/file` then run`cp /proc/[PID]/fd/1 /some/other/new/file` and remove duplicated data.  I'm not sure what's going to happen with the process terminates, though.